# installing cmake on Mac (skbuild not found error)

Tags: python, macos, cmake, player-stage

I was trying to install p/s following these steps
Link: http://jessicaaustin.net/installing-playerstage-on-os-x-leopard/

In step 2, I tryed 'pip install cmake'

[MacBook-Air:~ DAN$ pip install cmake
Collecting cmake
  Downloading cmake-0.6.0.tar.gz (33.7MB)
    89% |████████████████████████████▌   | 30.0MB -265183bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▌   | 30.0MB -241230bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.0MB -173692bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.0MB -173711bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.1MB -164223bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.1MB -183786bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.1MB -164140bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.1MB -155566bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.1MB -515676bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
89% |████████████████████████████▋   | 30.1MB -395430bytes/s eta -1 day, 23:    
100% |████████████████████████████████| 33.7MB 20kB/s 
    
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    
Traceback (most recent call last):
      
File "", line 1, in 
      
File "/private/var/folders/vv/qxzv12kx34zdq2xv080myyxc0000gq/T/pip-build-s_l0sewb/cmake/setup.py", line 7, in 
        
from skbuild import setup
    
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbuild'

this error happend.

what should I do?

Comment: You say you're following the instructions on that website, but nowhere does it say to use `pip` at all. It says install MacPorts and use the `port install` command.

Answer (score 1):

Read the instructions again. Nowhere does it say to use `pip`. You need to install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/install.php) and then follow the instructions that are on that page which say to install using `sudo port install cmake`.

Comment: thanks. I just restarted the terminal, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To close the loop, few days ago we released per-platform generic cmake python wheels, the error discussed above should now be fixed.